# C/C++ code highlighting looks weird in a web page

Tags: c++, html, emacs, syntax-highlighting, org-mode

My emacs have a black background and white text. If I convert org-files to html code-highlighting will probably look weird. In particular, the displayed "main" and "[]" are basically invisible.

How to make it look beautiful, or at least clearly readable？

[image: see here]
<sub>(source: [newsmth.net](http://att.newsmth.net/nForum/att/Emacs/101182/527))</sub>

Comment: Ensure that you are using monospaced font like Consolas.

Comment: Could you simply use a black background for code snippets on your webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what your problem is, but if you just need a good color scheme for code-highlighting, try [solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized), it's an amazing color scheme, and there is a theme for emacs already made by someone.